# Como listar todos os arquivos numa pasta usando Python?

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou construindo um programa que precisa conhecer os arquivos no diretorio de trabalho dele. Por isso, digitei o seguinte codigo.

```
def encontrar_arq(cadena, caminho):
   encontrado = False
   # lista_arq = ls(caminho) #funcao que lista todos os arquivos do caminho
   for nome_arq in lista_arq:
       if nome_arq == cadena:
           encontrado = True
   return encontrado
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem algumas formas, uma delas é a função [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
from os import listdir

def encontrar_arq(cadena, caminho):
   encontrado = False
   lista_arq = listdir(caminho)

   for arquivo in lista_arq:
      # Use "arquivo" aqui...
```

Para listar os arquivos e diretórios separadamente, use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
from os import walk

def encontrar_arq(cadena, caminho):
   encontrado = False

   for path, diretorios, arquivos in walk(caminho):
       for arquivo in arquivos:
           # Use "arquivo" aqui...
```

Uma outra alternativa é o [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
from glob import glob

def encontrar_arq(cadena, caminho):
   encontrado = False

   arquivos = glob(caminho + '.*') # Para listar somente .txt altere para "*.txt"
   for arquivo in arquivos:
       # Use "arquivo" aqui...
```

Comment: Obrigado @stderr, estou com outros problemas no meu codigo, dai ainda não consegui rodar a tua solução. Por isso a implementação que fiz ainda não a consegui testar. Mas logo ao testar valoro a resposta.

Comment: @AdolfoCorrea Disponha, qualquer dúvida só avisar!