# Configurar o .gitignore para não subir certos arquivos

Tags: git

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto .Net e gostaria de adicionar alguns arquivos para não subir no Github através do `.gitignore`. Comecei a pesquisar sobre e vi algumas soluções, das quais não entendi.

Então, primeiro, posso adicionar todos arquivos de obj e bin em meu .gitignore, não acontecerá nenhum problema?

Segundo, considerando a estrutura:

```
-Aplication
| -src 
| | - Domain
| | | - bin
| | | - obj
```

Como eu faria pra ignorar toda essa pasta **bin** e toda a pasta **obj**?

Comment: Tente usar esse `.gitignore` quando for usar projetos no Visual Studio https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore , ele abrange quase tudo que vc normalmente não precisa subir

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida mais prático fazer build out-of-tree (em pasta fora do projeto/solução)...normalmente usado com cmake, com Visual Studio puro não sei se dá pra fazer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Se o `.gitignore` estiver no mesmo nível que a pasta `Application` então adicione isto no `.gitignore`:

```
Aplication/src/Domain/bin/*
Aplication/src/Domain/obj/*
```

E salve o documento, faça a checagem no git, desta forma deve ignorar somente o conteúdo das pastas.

Se quiser ignorar o conteúdo **e as pastas** também, faça isso:

```
Aplication/src/Domain/bin/
Aplication/src/Domain/obj/
```

Answer (score 8):

Gostaria de por algumas considerações a mais do que as que existem nas respostas do [@GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237834/64969) e do [@BrunoFelipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237835/64969). São considerações genéricas da estrutura do `.gitignore` para referência extra/referência futura.

Como o Guilherme falou, você pode fazer menção a caminho com `*` para pegar os arquivos. Do exemplo dele:

```
Aplication/src/Domain/bin/*
Aplication/src/Domain/obj/*
```

Mas esse asterisco é mais poderoso do que só indicar **todos os arquivos em uma pasta**. E isso devido ao modo como o `.gitignore` é interpretado.

No `.gitignore`, você informa um conjunto de caminhos. Esses caminhos são interpretados como `glob` do `shell`. Isso permite algumas coisas bacanas, como por exemplo, para usuários do `vim`:

```
.*.sw[po]
```

Isso indica que todo arquivo oculta/começado por `.`, cujo fim é `.swp` ou `.swo`, vai ser ignorado.

> No `vim`, um arquivo de *swap* é criado no momento em que você edita um arquivo. Então, ao editar o arquivo `resposta.txt`, é criado um `.resposta.txt.swp`. Se por acaso o `vim` pare de maneira inesperada (sem apagar o arquivo temporário `.resposta.txt.swp`) e eu abra novamente o arquivo `resposta.txt`, o `vim` vai criar o `.resposta.txt.swo` e sugerir resgatar as mudanças não aplicadas do `.resposta.txt.swp`.
>
> ---
>
> Mais sobre `glob`:
>
> - [procurando arquivos PHP para incluir em código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98532/64969)
> - [procurando `gif`s na pasta atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179737/64969)
> - [áudios no formato `mp3` ou `wav` dentro da pasta de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205423/64969)
> - [usando `glob` com [tag:Python]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153552/64969)
> - [um exemplo de `glob` usado no [tag:Shell](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212632/64969)

Algo que é muito comum é encontrar para ignorar os arquivos compilados. No [java](/questions/tagged/java), normalmente eu ponho os seguintes:

```
*.class
*.jar
*.war
```

Mas isso pode ser perigoso se você usa o `maven`/`graddle` *wrapper*. Nesses casos, faz sentido commitar o jar de *wrapper*. Como fazer isso com `.gitignore`? Simples, você pode negar uma exclusão pondo uma exclamação `!` no começo da linha:

```
*.class
*.jar
*.war
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
```

Note que o único `jar` que vai aparecer será o que está localizado em `.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar`.

Também tem outra característica interessante: ignorar `src/Domain/obj/` e ignorar `/src/Domain/obj/` tem efeitos distintos. Por quê? Bem, vamos para o exemplo.

Suponha que tenhamos os seguintes arquivos modificados (considerando `.` a base do diretório [git](/questions/tagged/git)):

```
./.gitignore
./src/Domain/obj/marmota.o
./test-project/src/Domain/obj/marmota-teste.o
```

Caso o conteúdo do `.gitignore` seja `src/Domain/obj/`, o único arquivo que vai ser acusado de mudança será o próprio `.gitignore`.

Agora, se for `/src/Domain/obj/`, então os arquivos exibidos serão o `.gitignore` e o `marmota-teste.o`.

Quando você bota a barra no começo da linha, você está forçando que o arquivo sendo ignorado seja referente à raiz onde está o `.gitignore`.

Mais um último detalhe, você pode especificar `.gitignore`s distintos por diretório.

Por exemplo:

```
./.gitignore
./src/.gitignore
./resources/.gitignore
```

O primeiro `.gitignore` se aplica globalmente. O `src/.gitignore` não interfere na pasta `./resources`, e também o `resources/.gitignore` não interfere na pasta `./src`

Answer (score 5):

O que você adicionar no arquivo .gitignore não será enviado ao seu repositório git.

Conforme descrito no [documento oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): "O arquivo gitignore especifica arquivos intencionalmente não versionados que o Git deve ignorar. Arquivos que já estão sendo versionados pelo Git não serão afetados."

Assim, você pode criar o .gitignore na raiz do seu projeto, e para sua estrutura, colocar:

```
# Linhas iniciadas em # são comentários
src/Domain/bin/
src/Domain/obj/
```

Isso garantirá que as pastas bin e obj, e consequentemente, todo conteúdo delas, não serão enviadas ao servidor.