# Como excluir arquivos da minha HEAD remota e local do meu git mas não excluir do meu disco?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Eu tenho alguns arquivos que eu subi na minha HEAD remota e local do Git, mas agora preciso excluir estes arquivos mas preciso deixá-los no meu ambiente local de desenvolvimento. Estes arquivos não podem ir para o remoto por serem arquivos privados.

Comment: Você já commitou esses arquivos?

Comment: Sim, eu não ligo de ter esses arquivos no histórico, mas não quero que eles apareçam nos próximos commits

Comment: Então você vai precisar reescrever o histórico

Comment: Eu não ligo de ter esses arquivos no histórico, só quero excluir eles para que nos próximos commits, eles não apareçam no repositório

Comment: o git sempre mantém histórico de tudo commitado. Se você commitou uma vez na vida dados privados, eles estarão presentes na árvore de commits para todo o sempre

Comment: Cara, não sei se você entendeu, mas eu não ligo de estarem na árvore, eu só quero excluir para que não aparece no próximo commit que eu der, só preciso deles no meu pc, eu não preciso deles quando eu der um próximo git pull

Comment: Seria melhor tirar da árvore então, ou por no gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Utilizando git rm --cached**

Como você não se importa com o fato de o arquivo continuar em commits anteriores tudo fica mais fácil:

1. Primeiramente, inclua no seu .gitignore o nome dos arquivos que você
   pretende deletar, [como indicado pelo @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237830/configurar-o-gitignore) nos comentários da
   pergunta.

   > echo arquivo_que_nao_vou_mais_querer >> .gitignore
2. Agora use `git rm --cached` para deletar o arquivo do repositório
   local, mas não do disco:

   > git rm --cached arquivo_que_nao_vou_mais_querer

Assim o arquivo foi removido do git, mas não do diretório em si:

```
nunks@yokoi:~/test$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    arquivo_que_nao_vou_mais_querer

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore
```

3. Agora pode efetuar o commit e o push tranquilamente.

Comment: Valeu cara, isso foi exatamente o que eu estava querendo. Obrigado!