# Como ignorar a uma subpasta com gitignore

Tags: git

Como ignorar a uma subpasta com gitignore?
no meu caso apenas a subpasta /vendor

Minha estrututa

> /
>
> /systema/vendor

meu git está na ráiz do projeto meu gitignore também

```
!systema/
systema/vendor/*
```

tentei fazer esse procedimento mais o git ignora minha pasta systema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Configurar o .gitignore para não subir certos arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237830/configurar-o-gitignore-para-n%c3%a3o-subir-certos-arquivos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um **.gitignore** dentro do diretório */systema/* e coloque o código abaixo:

```
 [^.]*
```

Assim você vai estar ignorando todos arquivos e subpastas;

Para ignorar só a pasta */systema/vendor/* adicione o código abaixo;

```
/systema/vendor/
```

ou

Crie **.gitignore** dentro do diretório */systema/vendor/* adicione o código abaixo:

```
[^.*]
```

Comment: eu editei a pergunta,
quero apenas remover a sub pasta /vendor dentro da pasta systema.

Comment: Crie um .gitignore dentro do diretório /systema/vendor, e coloque 
o codigo [^.]*
Que irá resolver