# Arquivos de TypeScript no histórico de versão

Tags: javascript, typescript, git, github, mercurial

Comecei a utilizar o TypeScript em meus projeto web para gerar os arquivos JavaScript e minha dúvida é: No sistema de versão eu devo colocar apenas os arquivos JavaScript, TypeScript ou ambos?

Comment: Se alguma resposta solucionou o seu problema, marque ela como solução! Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079)

Answer (score 5):

Depende do que está fazendo e deseja.

Se está criando uma aplicação normal em TypeScript o seu código é nessa linguagem, esses arquivos são o fonte (*source*) da sua aplicação e está falando do uso de controle de versões de fontes (ainda que algumas pessoas usem para outras coisas não costuma ser o mais adequado, por isso tem até maneiras de ignorar certos arquivos, em geral os arquivos alvo).

Cada software de VCS tem sua própria forma de fazer isso, mas não é o foco da pergunta.

Os arquivos JS são o alvo (*target*) e por isso não quer controlar versão deles, são gerados a cada modificação, eles não existem por si só, são gerados sob demanda conforme vai mudando os fontes originais.

Quando você cria uma aplicação em outras tecnologias que geram um binário (um `.exe` por exemplo) você quer versionar esse arquivo? Acho que não. É a mesma coisa.

Mas pode ter algum caso que os `.js` podem ser úteis, só não é o mais comum, você teria que dar uma boa justificativa para fazê-lo. Um deles é você misturar as duas linguagens.

Comment: São projeto web com apenas html, css e javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Para indicar o que vai ou não para o seu repositório, você deve indicar o caminho do arquivo (ou diretório) em questão no seu arquivo [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Para mais detalhes, veja [Configurar o .gitignore para não subir certos arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237830/100416).

**O que ignorar?**

Bom, dependendo da linguagem / *framework* que você utilizar terá uma recomendação diferente. Veja [este repositório](https://github.com/github/gitignore) do GitHub, ele contém um `.gitignore` "padrão" para várias linguagens e *frameworks*.

No seu caso em específico, você não precisa versionar o `javascript` se ele é gerado a partir do `typescript`. Pois qualquer outro desenvolvedor que participar do projeto conseguirá gerar os arquivos `javascript` conforme necessitar.

Vale ressaltar que, caso você tenha um arquivo que não quer expôr as informações (por exemplo, um arquivo com as credenciais de um banco de dados ou com uma chave privada de acesso a uma API), você pode adicionar o arquivo no `.gitignore` para não publicá-lo :)

Comment: Sim, somente o que ignorar. São projetos simples com apenas com HTML, CSS e javascript rodando no lado do cliente.

Comment: Se o `javascript` é gerado a partir do `typescript`, você não precisa versionar o `javascript`. Mas na hora de fazer o *deploy* o recomendado é o contrário: enviar o HTML, CSS e JS, sem o TS