# Devo enviar para meu repositório Git os arquivos estáticos gerados pelo collectstatic do Django?

Tags: django, git

Após gerar os arquivos estáticos do meu web app usando:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Estou na dúvida se devo enviar ou não o conteúdo gerado no diretório `static/` para meu repositório. É uma boa prática versionar estes arquivos no Git?

Comment: Apesar [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447686/100416) ser sobre JavaScript, é relacionado e pode te esclarecer um pouco

Comment: Tecnicamente **não**, já que você provavelmente teria que refazer o build a cada modificação, na maior parte dos programas semelhantes nunca se envia as versões estaticas, claro que não fará mal algum também, mas enviar arquivos comprimidos/minificados e com nomes baseados em hashs, que pode haver mais de um, pois geralmente os antigos não são removidos instantaneamente a cada versão, então só iria atrapalhar o entendimento do histórico do que fez no seu fluxo do GIT.

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeito com a mesma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mais importante do que a resposta, diria que são 2 perguntas que devem ser feitas: `por que?` e `para que?` você faria isso.

- O conteúdo estático não é código versionado, é código gerado.
- Obrigaria um processo manual em todos os commits para atualizar o código gerado (poderia ser automatizado, mas não é algo trivial nessas condições).
- Em muitas ocasiões são gerados novos ficheiros com nomes completamente distintos, o que faria o seu repositório aumentar de tamanho vertiginosamente.

Se pretende "guardar" o código estático gerado, crie um processo de CI/CD, para criar versões junto dos seus commits/releases e publique em algum outro lugar "separado" do seu repositório. E coloco *separado* com aspas porque é possível organizar o mesmo junto do seu repositório no github, gitlab e afins. Dessa forma é possível separar o que é código, no seu repositório GIT, do que é gerado, para ser usado posteriormente, e ainda assim ter uma ligação e rastreio entre ambos.