# O que eu coloco no gitignore?

Tags: git, github

Estou aprendendo a mexer no `git` e `GitHub` essas semanas. Me deparei com uma certa dúvida:

Descobri que podemos colocar um arquivo `.gitignore` no nosso projeto para ele "ignorar" certos arquivos, então, é necessário mesmo usar ele? Que tipo de arquivos eu coloco nele?

Também estou criando uma aplicação em `typescript`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vendo esses arquivos, tem algum que eu posso ignorar antes de subir no gitHub?

Comment: Não é necessário usar. Vê [isto](https://fjorgemota.com/gitignore-ou-como-ignorar-arquivos-no-git/). Para NodeJs é conveniente ignorar a pasta `node_modules` pois qualquer um que tenha o código poderá fazer `npm install` para instalar as dependências.

Comment: O gitignore é usado para você não versionar arquivos desnecessários do projeto. Toda linguagem de programação possui alguns arquivos que são gerados quando você compila o projeto porém esses arquivos não são uteis para quem for baixar e executar o projeto e nesses casos são definidos arquivos ou pastas que devem ser desconsiderados quando você for versionar alguma coisa.

Comment: Relacionado: [Arquivos de TypeScript no histórico de versão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447686/100416)

Comment: coloca nele o que ignorar, depende do projeto, arquivos jar, exe, dll, etc

Answer (score 2):

O arquivo oculto **.gitignore** irá permitir que decidas quais os arquivos que estão no teu repositório local que não queres que suba para o repositório remoto, como o nome o diz eles serão ignorados mesmo que faças alguma alteração nelas.

Por exemplo, certos arquivos que são gerados automaticamente por uma determinada linguagem de programação ou até ficheiros com credenciais como exemplo, isto depende de cada caso é claro.

Algo interessante com os documentos **.gitignore** é que te permite usar certas macetes. Por exemplo, ignorar todos os arquivos com uma determinada extensão poderás o fazer da seguinte maneira:

*.pdf

Podes aceder a este repositorio do github:

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Nele estão diversos arquivos .gitignore para diversas linguagens do programação como java, javascript, python entre outras que acredito que iram te ajudar e pessoalmente uso e acabo adicionando outras coisas.
Espero ter te ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Kaiky Santos,

O arquivo .gitignore não é obrigatório para a sua aplicação, porém, ele é de grande ajuda quando você não pretende não subir um arquivo ou pasta especifico.

Abaixo segue alguns links úteis sobre gitignore e alguns exemplos de gitignore para nodejs e typescript.

Link sobre gitignore: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Link contendo exemplo simples de gitignore nodejs: https://gist.github.com/ericelliott/a9c8e7810d94fdd90993e30552674244

Link para debatendo sobre gitignore typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679722/gitignore-js-files-made-from-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Bem, no gitignore você pode adicionar arquivos que não serão necessários no repositório, como pasta de módulos, arquivos de testes etc. Este arquivo serve basicamente para facilitar seu dia, voce não precisa enviar arquivos desnecessários para seu repositório!

Até mais, e tenha um ótimo dia!